# How deploy a .war web project in Karaf 3?

Tags: osgi, war, karaf

With Karaf 3 I can deploy wab project and war project. 
I have made a no OSGi web project . I want to deploy that on Karaf 3. How to do it ?

Using netbeans ,  I have made a war file from my web project and I have  install on Karaf 3 the .war project using that : bundle:install -s file:/path/myproject.war 
I have no error for the install. 
But  I can't see that working when I go to `http://localhost:8181/myproject` .

Then Why that don't work? What is the problem ?

Thank you for your advice and help,

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install the war feature first

```
feature:install war
```

Comment: Shouldn't be present also features "http" and "http-whiteboard"? And what about "Web-ContextPath" and "Webapp-Context" manifest entries?

Comment: The feature http is already contained in the war feature. You can add http-whiteboard but for war files you typically do not need it.

Comment: Ah thanks! What about the manifest entries? From what I understood they are both required

Answer (score 0):

Install the war feature first, with feature:install war as Christian already mentioned. 
Though for a no-osgi war you'll need to install it with the **webbundle** prefix.

```
bundle:install webbundle:file:/path/myproject.war?WebContext-Path=myproject
```

Pax Web will create a OSGi war from it on the fly and this will be installed.

Comment: Well I take an error `Duplicate Import:javax.servlet.jsp` now.@Achim